# XLSX Writer - Issue with wrapping text and setting row height in a worksheet

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I was hoping someone could help me figure out an issue I'm having with setting row heights using XLSX Writer.

Essentially, what I am doing is:

1. Setting a cell format
2. Write data (code not included) into specific cells within a worksheet and applying the preset cell format
3. Iterating through the different rows and columns to set the row height and column width to specific dimensions

The issue I am running into is with the second portion of my code. Whenever I apply the specific height and column dimensions, they do not seem to actualize in my underlying spreadsheet. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
# first part of formatting code

ws = wb.add_worksheet()
cell_format1 = wb.add_format({'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'vcenter','align':'center'})
cell_format1.set_font_size(9)
cell_format1.set_font_name('Arial')

ws.hide_gridlines(2)

# second part of formatting code

fixed_box_height = 45
fixed_box_width = 16

for row in range(k2):
    if (row%2!=0):
        ws.set_row(row,fixed_box_height)

for column in range (k1+1):
    if (column%2!=0):
        ws.set_column(column,column,fixed_box_width)
```

#image for example

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear from the description what isn't working. Can you clarify what you are currently getting and what you expect to get.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "they do not seem to actualize in my underlying spreadsheet"?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your response! I know this will sound odd, but essentially what i am trying to do is populate text into a given cell with the above formatting and than limit the size of that cell regardless of the length of text in it. Therefore, in some cases, we will have text be cut off. When I attempt to change the size of the cell, the set_row / set_column method are not changing the cells dimensions, which default to whatever size is appropriate for the text populating it. I have included an image of what my current output is vs what my expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension change to the rows and columns should work as expected. Here is a working example based on your code snippets which shows the expected output:

```py
import xlsxwriter


wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

cell_format1 = wb.add_format({'text_wrap': True,
                              'valign': 'vcenter',
                              'align': 'center',
                              'font_size': 9,
                              'font_name': 'Arial'})

ws.write(3, 1, 'Some longish text to wrap in the cell', cell_format1)

k1 = 11
k2 = 12

fixed_box_height = 45
fixed_box_width = 16

for row in range(k2):
    if (row % 2 != 0):
        ws.set_row(row, fixed_box_height)

for column in range(k1+1):
    if (column % 2 != 0):
        ws.set_column(column, column, fixed_box_width)


wb.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Maybe update this example to create a small working program to debug your issue and if you still have some problems then update the example in your question.

Comment: thanks jmcnamara, im going to take this away and work on it some more. As a follow up, is it possible that the cell_format or the text being inserted into the cells before resizing them is limiting them from being resized?

Comment: @frostycanadian No. That isn't how xlsxwriter works. See the updated example. However, Excel does adjust the cell height for wrapped text when the row height hasn't been specified (not your case).

Comment: thank you for the response, i just tested it out on a smaller scale and it is working as expected. Looks like ill have to debug the main script and see where the disconnect it. I appreciate the response!